# Extract function arguments from overloaded function based on argument value (Vue 3 emits)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm struggling with getting the parameters of overloaded function (Vue). I was wondering if it is possible to extract function arguments from this code

```
type Emits = ((event: "confirm", value: number) => void) & ((event: "cancel", test: string) => void);
type ConfirmAction = Emits extends ((event: 'confirm', ...args: infer T) => void) ? T : never;
```

Unfortunately this solution gives `never`. I'd like to extract the specific rest arguments if `event` value is `confirm`.
I would expect the ConfirmAction to become `[number]`.

Here is some example of what I'd like to achieve:
https://play.vuejs.org/#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

Comment: Are you looking something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mALE4N)

Comment: It seem to work, but the use case here would be to get all emits from component and find one with `event: 'confirmed'`, take it's args and then make a type from it, so parent component would know the type of the first argument passed to `$emit('confirmed', data)` callback (infer `data` value in that case). Please, check the example above.

Comment: TypeScript *really* doesn't want to programmatically analyze overloads, see [ms/TS#43301](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43301). There are various type system loopholes you can try to exploit to tease out such info, giving you [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mpz7Xw) for example (it links to the relevant comment) but it's essentially unsupportable.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I was able to do that with Vue, because Vue exposes component definition with inferred emits as props.

```
import Comp from './Comp.vue';
type InferConfirm<Cmp> = Cmp extends { onConfirm?: (data?: infer P, ...args: any[]) => any }
    ? P
    : never;

// this one infers string
type InferredEmittedValue = InferConfirm<InstanceType<typeof Comp>>;
```

https://play.vuejs.org/#eNqdVl9v2zYQ/yoHPUwyYMjY8qbJatMkAzKsm9Eae4n6wEh0okYmBZKyG2j+7rsjJZmOlRRtXkLfP/7u7ndHdcFl08S7lgdJkOpCVY0BzU3bQM3EwzIPjM6DLBfVtpHKQAdXEk+CCzOHT2w/h0v9LIpR+JdkJVcvpf80ppJCz4/Oq/a+ropboQ0TBZ9DyTeV4Kdec9gy9WQvubbqUQMH2Ci5hRBxhyM2UvfyeEE/KK3wdw/7rTBcbVjBr3lRM8UI1Rjr/T275/XCPDdck1cuCsRsoMaUToHBEtI18G+Gi1Ifc0JxlwvAP8H3EM2S19LF4IcscqbFYPIHK4xUz8lkQdN1Bv9NFxVVuZjBMhuqFU3VMnp5z2xmU6Rs4QMrnkolGz+TCCOlo4BuH384T1ecIpn0prO1qoaKw+dHuT8zHXM4DzKU90yTuSqPCSVw7k0VHtO7FRuurqTYVGqbXm2bjAAiVYYbOpCiV79LICqZYfi/Ii9YzSGOY6YedAJMPN99sZXGE2B86t87WLlDgl3fcWWzXizAPFYa43IXR4M2qhIPPiLFy5ttZQwv/2V1yxHUCdCBLGt0SMlLbmxZs+zYuI+yZPUnrtvapA7F2hNdYyIYtRVPQu7F/NzgI3/V4IquRjOmcUJ8EypeB8r6JxDqtii41iFOMN6GrXh5/wGZ49lvWFWjsbKBB/OTyw4euxTb43UDryl74p5Nfc1RvwSvMMeyXKKC9Hfh2NjwixdWT1GRhrqvwA+QcaKqbzZyIvYv0OG+oHXRHbBcWXYS86d61O+W7jgkcEh+dAJprSSwwt1YaZ76VPOznXs4h7MPLEPC9BML2HbTKmHXYx83ipAast5xO1e9mTO14qh7lWq//nYBTLtZJFqQlz04Bk02OfJKkpwSC31j88iFRYQ3HgFVG+hlsfsHy+XyiGc2wJ7gpbO/CwmxpaBb+URC4wz7wGRg1bhWbBK5SBfuOcY+4A/Dt03NDMdfAHYxw3sMRAzDRzra0QqxkO0pD2CBlunCcwvm+JZbl4f4K3YGH3wLPA+oJFXNVc+FPEAqOqh5wOpa7v+0MqNa3hMQfR558TQh/6q/kSwPVpgZVzuEMuoM7lFunPrm8984VJ5yK8u2Rus3lMg4WbeE0Zl9aEWJsD07i/bWPve4bdf6huZWD0kRUFtja58H+HlAhXwt9SPci/hi6A1Wcfi0+M4Xk2szxxWPbXZvMu17nfbPl+1dAne2YUn/QDiOFHaAUEck8VX42TAjOlDUKOxj4ESEZBgSb95iTVnt7AGPupbGUgTPCyc/Jcvhf2uQhM0=